# CSS issue, table not filling up screen

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've been having an issue with a table that I want to fill the browser window. It's 3 columns wide, and 5 rows high. My desired outcome is that each cell is 33% of the width of the screen, and each cell is 20% of the height of the screen. There are no fixed values, instead I want to do everything with percentages, so that it resizes/stretches to always fill the browser.

The problem is that as I resize the browser although the width works perfectly, the height doesn't work in the same way. Even though I've specified each TR row as 20% high, it's not working in that way. What happens is that the bottom half of the screen remains empty, and the 5 rows aren't following the 20% height that I specified. In one bizarre instance (whilst trying things), the first row was 50% of the height, and the other 50% was the bottom 4 rows. Currently (as it is below), these 5 rows take up about 60% of the screen height, with the remaining 40% unused. Did I mention I hate CSS?

Here's the table:

```
<div id="portrait" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1 style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In each level, I'm defining the width and height, and then inside I'm defining a relative percentage bearing in mind the parent container. At the inner most level, where the image tag is, it's set to 100%x100% so that it fills it's container (width as 33% defined in the TD and height 20% defined in the TR).

Here's how I read the html above as far as the first image. The div is set to use 100% of the width of the browser, and 100% of the height. It contains only one item, a table. The table is defined to 100%x100%, but that's of course limited by it's parent container - the div, but as that is 100%x100% also, the table should be full browser size (IMHO). The TR defines width 100%, so it fills the width of the browser. It's set to 20% height, so I believe that means it should be fixed at 20% of the height of the table, which is 20% of 100% of the screen. The TD is defined as 33% width (3 columns of 33% to fill the browser), and height 100% (this column will fill 100% of it's parent TR, which is set to 20% of the browser height). Finally, the image is set to fill it's TR/TD and is therefore set to 100%x100%.

Comment: Your essay was too long for me to want to read, but most problems to do with `height` and percentages is due to the fact that they don't have a base height to work from - so try adding `html, body { height: 100% }` and see if this resolves your problem. If it doesn't, reword your question so it gets straight to the point.

Comment: And remove height from all td's

Comment: @My Head Hurts, it's hard finding the perfect balance between being too terse and have to answer a stream of questions and calls for more information, and being too verbose. I fell on the side of being too verbose this time :-(

Comment: I would recommend that you either use an external style sheet or embed using **style** tag.  It will make the code shorter, easier to understand, easier to change and there will be less to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/R3aCb/

And here is the working code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="portrait" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1 height="100%" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:100%;height:20%;">
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{height:100%;}​
```

Comment: Thanks SVS. That did solve the issue. It makes sense that the TD doesn't need a height (but I'm surprised having one was a problem). The body height makes perfect sense though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your styling.

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

​
And change your

```
<td style="width:33%;height:100%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
```

to

```
<td style="width:33%;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="x.jpg"></td>
```

You can see it here, http://jsfiddle.net/RFdSw/

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body{height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
            #mytable
            {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                table-layout:fixed;
            }           
            #mytable td
            {
                width;33%;
                height:19%;
            }
            #mytable td img
            {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="portrait" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="bg-bottom.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="x.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This should do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#portrait {
    height: 0;
}
table {
    height: 100%;
}
tr {
    height: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones coming here from a google search, in case this helps you:
I had `display:flex` on a `<td>` that apparently affected the `<tr>` and `<table>` itself.
After removing it, everything went back to normal.